# str_to_a32 - What does this function do?

Tags: python

I need to rewrite some Python script in Objective-C. It's not that hard since Python is easily readable but this piece of code struggles me a bit.

```
def str_to_a32(b):
    if len(b) % 4:
        # pad to multiple of 4
        b += '\0' * (4 - len(b) % 4)
    return struct.unpack('>%dI' % (len(b) / 4), b)
```

What is this function supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I'm using the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) to take a stab at it.

Looking at the docs, we're going to return a tuple based on the format string:

> Unpack the string (presumably packed by pack(fmt, ...)) according to the given format. The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The string must contain exactly the amount of data required by the format (len(string) must equal calcsize(fmt)).

The item coming in (`b`) is *probably* a byte buffer (represented as a string) - looking at the examples they are represented the the `\x` escape, [which consumes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0223/) the next two characters as hex.

It appears the format string is

```
'>%dI' % (len(b) / 4)
```

The `%` and `%d` are going to put a number into the format string, so if the length of b is 32 the format string becomes

```
`>8I`
```

The first part of the format string is `>`, which the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) says is setting the byte order to big-endian and size to standard.

The `I` says it will be an unsigned int with size 4 ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)), and the 8 in front of it means it will be repeated 8 times.

```
>IIIIIIII
```

---

So I think this is saying: take this byte buffer, make sure it's a multiple of 4 by appending as many `0x00`s as is necessary, then unpack that into a tuple with as many unsigned integers as there are blocks of 4 bytes in the buffer.

Comment: What does "a32" stand for?

Comment: @Wojtek The `32` probably refers to the size of an integer (32 bits == 4 bytes). The `a` could just be saying you'll get "a 32" or it could mean something else in the context of the code you're working with.

Comment: maybe array of 32bit integers (?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's supposed to take an input array of bytes represented as a string and unpack them as big-endian (the ">") unsigned ints (the 'I')   The formatting codes are explaied in http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

This takes a string and converts it into a tuple of Unsigned Integers.  If you look at [the python `struct` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) you will see how it works.  In a nutshell it handles conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings for handling binary data stored in files (unceremoniously copied from the link provided).

In your case, the function takes a string, `b` and adds some extra characters to make sure that it is the standard size of the an unsigned int (see link), and then converts it into a tuple of integers using the [big endian](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) representation of the characters.  This is the '>' part. The `I` part says to use [unsigned integers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)